# Grid of card in material-ui react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hello I'm trying to create that I had three cards in a row right now one after the other

Can't find a solution

Comment: Please add producible code

Comment: i try but "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." So I reacted again

Answer (score 0):

It's a complement

```js
const Posts = ({ setCurrentId }) => {
  const fuzzySearch = (list, searchValue) => {
    let buf = ".*" + searchValue.replace(/(.)/g, "$1.*").toLowerCase();
    var reg = new RegExp(buf);
    let newList = list.filter(function (e) {
      return reg.test(e.title.toLowerCase()&&e.message);
    });
    return newList;
  };
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
  const classes = useStyles();
   const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
  const [buttonnext, setbuttonnext] = useState(false);
  const [prebutton, setprebutton] = useState(true);
  
    const limit=8;
  const [startIndex,setstartIndex] = useState();
  const [endIndex,setendIndex] = useState();

  useEffect(()=>{
    setstartIndex((pageNumber-1)*limit)
    setendIndex(pageNumber*limit)
    console.log(startIndex)
    console.log(endIndex)

  },[posts,pageNumber])

  const Next = ()=>{

    if(pageNumber === (Math.floor((posts.length+limit -1)/limit))){
     setbuttonnext(true)
     
    }else{
      setPageNumber(pageNumber+1)
      setprebutton(false)
    }
  }
  const Previous = () =>{
  
    if(pageNumber === 1){
      setprebutton(true)
    }else{
      setPageNumber(pageNumber-1)
      setbuttonnext(false)
    }
  }
  


  return(

    !posts.length ? <CircularProgress /> : <>
    < >
    <AppBar className={classes.appBar} position="static" color="inherit">
    <Typography className={classes.heading} variant="h2" >קבוצות אחרונות</Typography>
       <Paper component="form" className={classes.root}>
     <IconButton className={classes.iconButton} aria-label="menu">
     </IconButton>
     <InputBase
       className={classes.input}
       placeholder="חיפוש "
       inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search ' }}
       value={searchValue}
       onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
 
     />
     <IconButton  className={classes.iconButton} aria-label="search">
       <SearchIcon />
     </IconButton>
     <Divider className={classes.divider} orientation="vertical" />
   </Paper>

   </AppBar>

   <ol>
     {fuzzySearch(posts, searchValue).slice(startIndex,endIndex).map((d) =>  (

<Grid key={d._id} item xs={10} sm={6} md={6}>
                <Grow in>

<Post post={d} setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
</Grow>
</Grid>)      )}

   </ol>
 </>
    <Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>

<Grid container direction="row-reverse"justifyContent="center"alignItems="flex-end" >

<>
                    <button className={classes.button} onClick={Next}>הבא</button>
                    &nbsp;
                    <p className={classes.numText}>{ pageNumber}</p>
                    &nbsp;
                    <Button className={classes.button} onClick={Previous}>אחורה</Button>
                    </>
                    </Grid>                   

              </Grid></>
  )
};
export default Posts;
```

Then called to app in app.js Grid in shape

```js
  return (
    <Container maxWidth="lg" >
      <Grow in>
        <Container>
              <Posts setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
        </Container>
      </Grow>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I would to create a grid that I had three in a row

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but I assume that you are trying to display 3 cards in a row. The idea is that [Material-UI is using flexbox](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/), and they are divided into 12 equal columns.

```js
<Grid spacing={2}>
  // Define grid for card items
  {
    data.map((dataItem) => (
      <Grid key={dataItem.id}>
        // ... items inside
      </Grid>
    ))
  }
</Grid>
```